# Book about human-like aliens with power of teleportation who initiate a galactic war against deficient (aka normal) humankind

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Spacefaring humans meet a race that is almost identical physically. But the aliens have the ability to teleport themselves. The normal humans are judged deficient by the human race who can teleport and (for some reason) determine to control the mentally deficient humans. Technologically, they are about the same level so a war ensues. The humans are losing but also have several victories. I recall a chapter where a human boy on an occupied world ambushes and kills a patrolling soldier who relied on his teleportation capability too much. There is an attraction between a teleporting human and a captured non-teleporting human that help resolves the conflict. Seems to me they find a way to prove that the non teleporting humans teleport. They just never learned how. Maybe Van Vogt? I thought it might be a Philip High story but apparently not. Asimov? Brunner? Rackam? Was that 1960s era.

Comment: Probably a long shot, but a bit of googling led me to Nancy Kress' *Probability Trilogy*, where humankind is at war with human-looking aliens called the Fallers. I can't determine if the Fallers are telepathic, but telepathy exists in the universe, so possibly they are. https://www.barnesandnoble.com/blog/sci-fi-fantasy/throwback-thursday-the-probability-trilogy-ranks-with-the-best-of-hard-sci-fi/